# Restricting records deletion

Tags: configuration, access

We have the following use case to be handled.

We have a custom object **PTemplates__c**.

*Except User A and all Sys Admins, no one should be able to delete the records of **PTemplates__c**.*

I believe permission sets are used to open access only as such I am not sure how to enforce the restriction on deletion.

Are there any properties/settings that deal specifically with deletion of records for one specific object ?

Comment: Go to user profile you find there delete property for specific object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. Permission set is not used to enforce the restriction but we can extend the functionality using that. That is why we will first restrict the functionality and after that we will extend using the permission set.

You can follow below steps to achieve this.

1. Remove delete permission from all profiles for Ptemplates__c
2. Create a permission set and add Delete rights into that.
3. Assign this permission set to User A.

Comment: Why should we keep the OWD as "Private"...I can keep it as "Public Read Only" right ?

Comment: yes you can do that. the basic idea is to understand the permission set logic :)